# Can no longer boot Ubuntu after setting GRUB_DEFAULT=2

Tags: boot, grub2, encryption

I can no longer login to my computer after messing with the GRUB setup.

In `/etc/default/grub` to revert to an older kernel I changed

`GRUB_DEFAULT=2`

now I can no longer login into my system, it does no longer boot and goes straight to the BIOS setup.

To make things worse, I have an encrypted hard drive (fortunately `/boot` is not encrypted) and I am unable to mount it in the Ubuntu I am currently running from an USB stick.

How can I fix GRUB to revert to the latest kernel when only being able to access the boot partition?

I have tried `boot-repair`, but this is unable to fix the issue. However, it at least created the following analysis in the pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fbxDRhbZTh/

Thanks!

Comment: Idea: Could I simply change `set default="2"`  in the `grub.cfg`? Or will this make things worse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, changing `set default="2"` to `set default="0"` in the `grub.cfg` on `/boot` partition fixed the issue.

Comment: Mate, accept this answer then

Comment: You cannot accept your own answers straight away ;-) I have to wait 2 days to do that.